# Python 3: When is a call to an instance attribute resolved as if it is an instance method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, instance-methods

```
class C:
  def func(self, a):
    print(a)

c = C()
print(c.__dict__) # {}
c.func = c.func
# c.func is now an instance attribute, which hides instance method
print(c.__dict__) # {'func' : (bound method C.f of (__main.C object at ...))}
# how come it still works as if it's an instance method:
c.func(1) # prints 1

# with a regular function assigned to c.func, this won't happen:
def newfunc(self, a):
  print(a)
c.func = newfunc
c.func(1) # TypeError
```

What are the conditions under which a call `c.func(1)` magically adds the instance `c` as the first parameter?  I thought it only happens when `func` was defined as an instance method in the class. But it seems it *sometimes* works when `func` is just an instance attribute.

Comment: because `c.func` is no longer a plain function but a bound method to an instance

Comment: Shouldn't `def newfunc(self, a):` be `def newfunc(a):` ?

Comment: @Larry: No. Methods take the instance as the first parameter.

Comment: @LarryBattle: that's my point. The first call to `c.func` magically inserted `c` as the first parameter, while the second call didn't. Note that in both cases `c.func` is "just" an instance attribute.

Comment: `c.func` is an instance attribute in both cases, but in one case that attribute's value is a bound method, while in the other case it is a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The binding to the instance happens when you *access* `c.func`, not when you call it.  When you do `c.func = c.func`, the attribute access on the right-hand side is handled by the class `C` and evalutes to a bound method.  Reassigning it to `c.func` assigns it to the instance, but it's already a bound method, so this doesn't change the behavior.

In your newfunc example, you just defined a function and assigned it, so it never got made into an instance method.  Since you assign it directly to an instance, the class doesn't get a chance to intercept the access and wrap it in an instancemethod.

You can assign a bound method anywhere you like and it remains bound to the instance via which you got it.  See these examples:

```
>>> class C(object):
...     def __init__(self, name):
...         self.name = name
...     def func(self, a):
...         print("Called {0} with {1}".format(self.name, a))
>>> one = C("one")
>>> two = C("two")
>>> one.func(1)
Called one with 1
>>> two.func(1)
Called two with 1
>>> one.func2 = two.func
>>> one.func2(1)
Called two with 1
```

Note that once I assigned `one.func2 = two.func`, calling `one.func2` calls an instance method bound to `two`, not `one`.  This is because when I accessed `two.func`, I got a method bound to that instance.  It doesn't matter where I assign it later.  It remains bound to the instance via which it was accessed.

If you access the unbound method directly and try to assign it elsewhere, then you get the TypeError because the method was never bound:

```
>>> one.func3 = C.func
>>> one.func3(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#16>", line 1, in <module>
    one.func3(1)
TypeError: unbound method func() must be called with C instance as first argument (got int instance instead)
```

Also note that if you add the method to the *class*, it will work when called on an instance, even if the instance was created before you added the method to the class.  Keeping the same `one` object from before, I can do:

```
>>> def newFunc(self, a):
...     print("Newfunc of {0} called with {1}".format(self.name, a))
>>> C.newFunc = newFunc
>>> one.newFunc(1)
Newfunc of one called with 1
```

To answer your question succinctly, `c.func` is bound to `c` if `c` is an instance of a class that has a method `func`, and `c` does not itself have an instance attribute `func`.  (If `c` did have an instance attribute of the same name, that overrides the class one, so the class doesn't get to do its wrapping to bind the method to the instance.)

Comment: How does Python determine whether "class has a method `func`"? Does it just check that it is a class attribute, and is callable? It doesn't seem like that, since if I assign `C.newFunc = len`, it doesn't get bound to instances of `C`, even though `len` is callable. If I understand the docs correctly, it only does this for user-defined functions?

Comment: @max: It has to be an object of type "function".  `len` doesn't work because its type is "builtin function".  Unfortunately builtin functions aren't the same as "real" Python functions, and this is one case where it shows up.  But you can see it work if you try a library function that's written in Python (e.g., `C.func = collections.namedtuple`).

Answer (score 1):

`c.func(1)` will magically add the instance `c` as the first parameter when the method `c.func` is bound to the object `c`.

Functions that are attributes of the class are automatically bound to instances of that class.  So immediately after `c = C()`, `c.func` is different from `C.func` in that it accepts one fewer argument and `c` magically becomes the first argument.  This is why `c.func = c.func` doesn't change anything, and everything works normally.

If you want to patch an instance of a class with a new instance method, you need to bind the function to the instance.  Here are a few options:

- Using `types.MethodType`:

  ```
  import types
  c.func = types.MethodType(newfunc, c)
  ```
- Using `functools.partial`:

  ```
  import functools
  c.func = functools.partial(newfunc, c)
  ```

Note that the second method mimics the behavior, but is slightly different because `type(c.func)` will be `<type 'functools.partial'>` instead of `<type 'instancemethod'>`, so the first method is probably preferable.

Comment: "Functions that are attributes of the class are automatically bound to new instances of that class" - it might become clearer if you delete the word "new". Otherwise, it might seem that pre-existing instances won't be bound to a newly defined class function.

Comment: +1 - thx, I didn't realize the relationship between `MethodType` and `partial`.